# How to add a picture next to the text/Header?

Tags: cv, picture-mode

I need you help. I want to write my CV with `LaTeX` and I got everything working except one thing.
I want to add a picture next to the header/first part of the CV.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\input{glyphtounicode}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape xxxxxxxxxx} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small Anschrift: xxxxxxxxxx $|$
    \small geb. xxxxxxxxxx $|$
    \small Tel: xxxxxxxxxx $|$ 
    \href{mailto:x@x.com}{E-Mail: xxxxxxxxxxx} $|$ 
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,right]{Bild.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\input{glyphtounicode}


\begin{document}


\vfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
\begin{center}
      \textbf{\Huge \scshape xxxxxxxxxx} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small Anschrift: xxxxxxxxxx $|$
    \small geb. xxxxxxxxxx $|$
    \small Tel: xxxxxxxxxx $|$ 
    \href{mailto:x@x.com}{E-Mail: xxxxxxxxxxx} $|$   
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

This will be the output:

[image]

You can also extract the tittle from the minipage and put it on top:
[image]